# Basic syntax checking algorithm for strings in arithmetic/ propositional logic/ Boolean algebra?

Tags: syntax

I would like to write a simple syntax-checking algorithm for strings in Boolean algebra, that will return true if & only if the string you pass it is well-formed.

In English, you could define the set of well-formed Boolean algebra formulae as follows: A letter, the integer 0, and the integer 1 are all well-formed formulae; the set of well-formed formulae is closed under negation (', unary, postfix) disjunction (+, binary, infix) and conjunction(*, binary, infix); and anything not well-formed by the two foregoing clauses is not well-formed.

So, binary connectives need to have a well-formed formula as an argument on either side, unary connectives must have a single well-formed argument, parentheses should be nested correctly... and so on.

I get the general idea of what needs to happen, but I'm unsure of how to convert it into an algorithm. Can anyone help?

Comment: You forgot parenthesis (maybe). Do you want to write it entirely by yourself or use some exiting helper software (libs)? Programming language?

Comment: I would like for it to be language-independent. Parentheses are a concern for sure.

Comment: However: I'm currently writing my program in Java, may port it to Javascript at some point, and a solution with libraries is preferable to no solution. : )

Comment: One other thing: My program already parses well-formed strings into tree structures by converting infix to postfix, then parsing postfix. I feel like there might be some way to leverage this into syntax checking, but am not sure.